# Star rating with half star support

Tags: php, html, svg

I am running into a problem rendering a star rating and was hoping I can get some extra eyeballs on my problem. I have the normal rating working just fine with whole numbers but I am struggling to display the half star. For example I created a service that provides me with a rating 0-5 so I get a value like 2.5, 3 or 5 etc...

Before I go and create a switch case and create an svg for each variation I was hoping to get a little a pointer. Below is what I have currently, any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalRating; $i++) {
     if($starRating < $i ) {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star-empty.svg\">";
      }
      else {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star.svg\">";
      }
    }
?>
```

Ideally I would like to add a condition at the end of the loop and check for the half and echo "";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably an easier way to do it but this works, checks if `$starRating` is a float and then rounds it up and checks against `$i` to place the half star in the correct position.

```
<?php
$totalRating = 5;
$starRating = 2.5;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalRating; $i++) {
     if($starRating < $i ) {
        if(is_float($starRating) && (round($starRating) == $i)){
            echo "<img src=\"/icons/star-half.svg\">";
        }else{
            echo "<img src=\"/icons/star-empty.svg\">";
        }
     }else {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star.svg\">";
     }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the value of **$starRating** is an integer, doing something like this (considering only half values):

```
<?php
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalRating; $i++) {
     if ($starRating < $i ) {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star-empty.svg\">";
     } elseif(is_int($starRating) === false) {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star_half.svg\">";
     } else {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star.svg\">";
      }
    }
?>
```

If you want to show stars with a more precise value you can create images with the float values in the name, like **"star-3.svg"** (representing a .3 float value, and do something like this:

```
<?php
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalRating; $i++) {
     if ($starRating < $i ) {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star-empty.svg\">";
     } elseif(is_int($starRating) === false) {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star-" . floatval($starRating)) . ".svg\">";
     } else {
        echo "<img src=\"/icons/star.svg\">";
      }
    }
?>
```

But in this case you need to take care to only receive float values with one number (2.2, 3.4, etc.).

I hope it helps...